# Maintain IMAP message state information (imap flags) when using Javamail

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, imap, gmail-imap

We have a java app built by third party that opens a read/write IMAP connections, and retrieves certain messages. However it also marks them as "read". I am guessing this is due to fact that  the app opens a read/write connection. Is there a way we can prevent this app from updating the "read (seen)" imap flag? Maybe a parameter we can set when opening the connection to the IMAP?

Comment: You need to make sure it uses body.peek, not body, when FETCHING messages. Using EXAMINE instead of SELECT should also open the mailbox in a read only way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Open](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/javax/mail/Folder.html#open%28int%29) the Folder [read-only](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/javax/mail/Folder.html#READ_ONLY) instead of read/write.

Comment: we need to open the folder read/write, because we set some custom user flags on the IMAP.

Comment: Ah, well, you didn't say that!  :-)  After fetching the Message objects, cast them to com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPMessage and use the [setPeek](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/com/sun/mail/imap/IMAPMessage.html#setPeek(boolean)) method.

Comment: for me this does not work - the seen flag is set although my folder is opened READ_ONLY

Comment: Are you setting the peek flag before accessing any content of the message?  Post the code that reproduces the problem and the [JavaMail debug output](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#debug).  Does the SEEN flag setting persist after the folder is closed and reopened?

Answer (score -1):

You can do this for a single message:

```
folder.setFlags(new Message[] {message}, new Flags(Flags.Flag.SEEN), false);
```

or for a list of messages:

```
folder.setFlags(messageList, new Flags(Flags.Flag.SEEN), false);
```

where `false` stands for UNREAD.

Comment: He doesn't want to mark a message unread.   He wants the message not to be marked read in the first place, when it is downloaded.